# Blank space/whitespace gets added automatically when updating NCHAR(2 CHAR) filed in oracle 12 c

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a table which contain a column of type NCHAR(2 CHAR).
It has data like .n and i want to update (.n) to just (N) but when i am updating teh field, it adds an extra white space after N (N ).

Kindly help on how can i just put one character in this column.

Comment: NCHAR fixes the length of the field. That means either use the full-length value or Oracle will append the blank spaces at the end of the value. To avoid this issue use VARCHAR2 instead of NCHAR.

Comment: okay ..so anyhow oracle will insert one character more even if i update just N as the size it fixed at 2 ? right?

Comment: Yes. Oracle will append space to fix the length to 2.

Comment: Okay .Thank You so much

Answer (score 2):

That's how the CHAR or NCHAR data type works, it's a fixed length string. Even if you insert a value of 'A' it will be stored as 'A '

What you want is VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2 - that's a varying character. So it will only take the amount of characters necessary to store your value.